# find method in a stack

Tags: visual-c++, stack

I've implemented a method to find a value from a 'Stack'. I just want to know that are there any logical errors or any kind of errors in this code?
Thanks.

```
  bool about::findData(char key)
{
  if(top==-1)
   cout<<"Stack is Empty"<<endl;
  else
  {
    for(int x=0; x<maxSize-1; x++)
    {
       if(stackArray[x]==key)
         return stackArray[x];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Variable 'top' is used nowhere else you probably did want to check the size of stackArray there? Elsewise it seems to do what you want - but it won't return anything if the value is not found (which is perfectly fine). Besides that: Why not try it out? :)

Comment: Found out that I can't even enter values to the stack. :/ The error message is "argument of type "const char* " is incompatible with parameter of type "char" " (This is a character stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what you want to do / ask. From a logical point of view this program will work.

But you got some hops and jumps in there. I will start with a working example and point out the differences.

Note that I won't address the [stack logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Array) in itself. It seems like you did start out with a stack like thing, but got driven quite away from it?

You have a `(top == -1)` query in there, but never ever declared top / assigned a value to it. I assumed that you meant the size of the array (not that this is probably not the best way to calculate the array size, especially as C++ has a vector container anyways).

You iterate over `maxSize` elements, yet didn't declare `maxSize` anywhere. This also assumes that your stack is of fixed size and all elements are initiated with a sane value. I am just iterating over the size of the current array right now.

You return the value `return stackArray[x];`, yet declared your function to have a `bool` return value - this does no harm in itself, but I went for returning `true` and `false` to adhere to the return value.

Try the code [online](http://ideone.com/65k5eQ).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int maxSize = 10;
char stackArray[] = {'b', 'a', 'c', 'd'};

//char stackArray[] = {};
bool findData(char key)
{
  int top = (sizeof(stackArray)/sizeof(*stackArray));
  cout << "Size of array is: " << top << endl;
  if(top <= 0)
   cout<<"Stack is Empty"<<endl;
  else
  {
    for(int x=0; x<top; x++)
    {
       if(stackArray[x]==key)
         return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

int main() {
    if(findData('a')) {
        cout << "We found the value!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "We didn't find the value!" << endl;
    }

}
```

---

### EDIT

And as I couldn't resist I jump started with an array based stack architecture from [here](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Stack/Array-based_implementation) and implemented our beloved `findValue` within this stack.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Stack {
private:
   int top;
   int capacity;
   int *storage;
public:
   Stack(int capacity) {
   if (capacity <= 0)
      throw string("Stack's capacity must be positive");
   storage = new int[capacity];
   this->capacity = capacity;
   top = -1;
   }

void push(int value) {
   if (top == capacity)
      throw string("Stack's underlying storage is overflow");
   top++;
   storage[top] = value;
 }

 int peek() {
    if (top == -1)
       throw string("Stack is empty");
    return storage[top];
 }

 void pop() {
    if (top == -1)
       throw string("Stack is empty");
    top--;
 }

 /* Our findValue function. */
 bool findValue(int key) {
    /* Now the usage of top makes perfect sense,
       the counter variable always contains the amount
       of stored elements. */
    if (top == -1) {
        throw string("Stack is empty");
    }

    /* We traverse all elements of our storage. */
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
        if(storage[i] == key) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }

bool isEmpty() {
   return (top == -1);
}

~Stack() {
   delete[] storage;
}
};


int main() {
    /* Init the new stack. */
    Stack* stack = new Stack(10);

    /* Push some elements for more fun. */
    stack->push('a');
    stack->push('b');
    stack->push('c');
    stack->push('d');
    stack->push('e');
    stack->push('f');

    /* Show charcode of last pushed element. */
    cout << stack->peek() << endl;

    /* Find 'e'. */
    if (stack->findValue('e')) {
        cout << "We found the value" << endl;
    }

    /* Try and not find 'g'. */
    if (!(stack->findValue('g'))) {
        cout << "We didn't find the value" << endl;
    }
    delete stack;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I implented all the codings and I posted here only the find method.

Comment: @LahiruHashan : Yeah, I realized that later on but didn't change my original answer. Consider [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions where you only want a check for sanity / design choices / functionality. As you did notice I wasn't able to give a very meaningful answer without proper code context and a clear question ;-)